# Convert ColorSpaces using OpenCv in Python

Tags: python, opencv, hsv, color-space, bgr

How do I convert an image within BGRA color space to HSV and BGRA to YCbCR? I only know convertion from BGR and not BGRA. Is the approach different or the same?

```
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
ycrcb_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
```

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Neither HSV, nor YCbCr include a transparency plane, so you just drop that, and convert the remaining BGR using the methods you mentioned.

Comment: @DanMašek Do you drop the alpha with `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)` or is there an easier/faster way to ditch the extra channel?

Comment: @MarkSetchell `cvtColor` is probably as good as you can get if you want to remove the plane altogether -- due to the layout it's a matter of erasing (or not copying) every 4th byte. However, if I'm reading the code correctly `BGR2HSV` will work with 4 channel input images as well, just ignoring the alpha plane. (Just checked it in interpreter, yes it does, same result for BGR or BGRA and contents of alpha plane make no difference on result)

Answer (score 3):

Neither HSV, nor YCbCr include a transparency plane, so the only thing the conversion could do with it is ignore it. As it turns out (after little digging through the implementation), `cvtColor` accepts both 3 and 4 channel input images for those conversion method, and correctly ignores the 4th (transparency) if present.

Little script to verify that:

```
import cv2
a = cv2.imread('car_1.png')
b = cv2.cvtColor(a, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
c = b.copy()
c[:,:,3] = 0

aa = cv2.cvtColor(a, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
bb = cv2.cvtColor(b, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cc = cv2.cvtColor(c, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

print (aa == bb).all()
print (aa == cc).all()
```

Prints `True` and `True`.

Same thing for BGR -> YCrCb